# Unable to write data in HDFS "datanode" - Node added in excluded list

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running "namenode" and "datanode" in the same jvm, when I try to write data I'm getting the following exception

org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicy$NotEnoughReplicasException: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseRandom(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseRandom(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseLocalRack(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseLocalStorage(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTargetInOrder(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:421)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.chooseTarget(BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2771)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:876)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1025)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:876)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:822)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2682)

```
        final File file = new File("C:\\ManageEngine\\test\\data\\namenode");
        final File file1 = new File("C:\\ManageEngine\\test\\data\\datanode1");
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        final HdfsConfiguration nameNodeConfiguration = new HdfsConfiguration();
        FileSystem.setDefaultUri(nameNodeConfiguration, "hdfs://localhost:5555");
        nameNodeConfiguration.set(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_NAMENODE_NAME_DIR_KEY, file.toURI().toString());
        nameNodeConfiguration.set(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_REPLICATION_KEY, "1" );
        final NameNode nameNode = new NameNode(nameNodeConfiguration);



        final HdfsConfiguration dataNodeConfiguration1 = new HdfsConfiguration();
        dataNodeConfiguration1.set(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_DATANODE_DATA_DIR_KEY, file1.toURI().toString());
        dataNodeConfiguration1.set(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_DATANODE_ADDRESS_KEY, "localhost:5556" );
        dataNodeConfiguration1.set(DFSConfigKeys.DFS_REPLICATION_KEY, "1" );
        FileSystem.setDefaultUri(dataNodeConfiguration1, "hdfs://localhost:5555");
        final DataNode dataNode1 = DataNode.instantiateDataNode(new String[]{}, dataNodeConfiguration1);



        final FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(dataNodeConfiguration1);

        Path hdfswritepath = new Path(fileName);
        if(!fs.exists(hdfswritepath)) {
            fs.create(hdfswritepath);
            System.out.println("Path "+hdfswritepath+" created.");
        }
        System.out.println("Begin Write file into hdfs");

        FSDataOutputStream outputStream=fs.create(hdfswritepath);
        //Cassical output stream usage
        outputStream.writeBytes(fileContent);
        outputStream.close();
        System.out.println("End Write file into hdfs");
```

[Request data - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8FAD.png)

Comment: You cannot have `replication number > number of data nodes`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your comment, but I want to run single datanode, is there any possible way to archive this.

Comment: Found this line in logs  "Failed to find datanode (scope="" excludedScope="/default-rack"). numOfDatanodes=0"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the number of replicas higher than the number of datanodes.

If you want run on a single node, set `dfs.replication` to 1 in your hdfs-site.xml.